# distinguish where the user has come from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios5

I can see there being a very simple answer to this but I will ask anyway. I have two viewControllers that navigate to the same viewController is there a way to distinguish which viewController the user has come from out of the two. As I need to run different methods based on which ever page they have come from?

Comment: What do you mean by "page"? Are these view controllers? When you "lead onto" the one page, how are you doing this?

Comment: Yes they are view controllers. I am using presentModalViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is just add a `NSString *previousPage;` as a `property` of your common page. When you go to your common page either page1 or page2, you just need to set the property of your common page and you can do anything that you want based on `previousPage` value.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing. I just didn't sound good in my head. Thought there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean with 'leading' ... when you leave one view and then show the other, you can of course just call a different method on the target view (or set some variable in it before switching to the view).